# How to name a column that is also a function name in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, this doesn't work,

```
SELECT a.score, a.r as Rank FROM 
    (SELECT score, dense_rank() over (order by Score desc) as r
        FROM Scores) a
ORDER BY a.r;
```

That is because `Rank` is also a function. I tried to replace `Rank` with `[Rank]` but that still doesn't work. So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a different name.  That is what I would recommend.  But absent that, the escape character in MySQL is the backtick:

```
SELECT a.score, a.r as `Rank`
FROM (SELECT score, dense_rank() over (order by Score desc) as r
      FROM Scores
     ) s
ORDER BY a.r;
```

Or the SQL standard, double quotes:

```
SELECT a.score, a.r as "Rank"
FROM (SELECT score, dense_rank() over (order by Score desc) as r
      FROM Scores
     ) s
ORDER BY a.r;
```